# How do you shutdown an embedded Undertow application?

Tags: java, undertow

In the [Undertow documentation](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html), the following example is presented as a very simple server:

```
public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

How does this server shutdown? There is a `server.stop()` method that presumably would shutdown the server gracefully, but it is not used in this example. Should there be a shutdown hook associated with the runtime that would call the `server.stop()` method?

Comment: Yes if you would like to shutdown the Server Gracefully you'll have to call the server.stop() Method else it will continue Running till its being interrupted.